# Unable to parse gcm.notification.data from push notification

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-cloud-messaging, unnotificationrequest

I am unable  to get `Data` Dictionary from Firebase push notification  .

**My Code** :

```
class func parseIncommingMessages(notification:UNNotification) {
    print("PushNotifications: \n \(notification.request.content.userInfo.debugDescription)")

    let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo as! [String: Any]
    let dicDataContainer = userInfo["gcm.notification.data"] as? [AnyHashable:Any]

    //       notification
    if let dicDataMain = dicDataContainer?["Data"] as? [String:Any] , let notificationType = dicDataContainer?["notificationType"] as? String
    {
            print("\nData: \(dicDataMain)")
            print("\n NotificationType: \(notificationType)")
    }

}
```

**PushNotifications:**

```
[AnyHashable("gcm.message_id"): 0:1544560847941727%a27b0018a27b0018, AnyHashable("google.c.a.e"): 1, AnyHashable("gcm.notification.data"): {"Data":{"Name":"a","message":"test","operation":"change"},"notificationType":"status_change"}, AnyHashable("aps"): {
    alert =     {
        body = Somthing;
        title = Somthing;
    };
}]
```

I am unable to parse , please help me....

Answer (score 3):

You can try

```
let str = userInfo["gcm.notification.data"] as! String
let res = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self,data:str.data(using:.utf8)!)
print(res?.data)
```

---

```
struct Root : Decodable {
    let data: DataClass
    let notificationType: String
}

struct DataClass : Decodable {
    let name, message, operation: String
}
```